# Inconsistent Styling using SvelteKit with Tailwind

Tags: build, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm currently working on a SvelteKit project and using Tailwind CSS for styling. However, I've encountered an issue that I hope someone can assist me with. The problem lies in the inconsistency between the styles I see when running the project using 'npm run dev' or 'npm run preview' versus the styles I get after the build process.

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem or have any ideas on what might be causing this issue? Are there any solutions or further troubleshooting steps I should try?

If you need any additional information, code snippets, or configuration files, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide them.

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: Consider reviewing the differences in the CSS code generated between the different commands – this may help you identify the misconfiguration or misuse.